# How to visualize Fourier series / Fourier coefficients?

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, fft

I'm currently having difficulties at visualizing Fourier series. I tried the same thing about three times in order to find errors but in vain.

Now I even don't know what is wrong with my code or understanding of Fourier series.

What I'm trying to make is a thing like shown in the following Youtube video: https://youtu.be/r6sGWTCMz2k

I think I know what is Fourier series a bit. I can prove this by showing my previous works:

(1) square wave approximation

[image: simple Fourier series]

(2) parameter

[image: circle (parametric)]

So now I would like to draw **more complicated thing in a parametric way**. Please let me show the process I've walked.

① From svg path, get coordinates. For example,

```js
// svg path
const d = 'M 0 0 L 20 30 L 10 20 ... ... ... Z';
↓
↓ convert with some processing...
↓
const cx = [0, 20, 10, ...]; // function Fx(t)
const cy = [0, 30, 20, ...]; // function Fy(t)
```

② Get Fourier coefficients from Fx(t), Fy(t), respectively. After that, I can get **approximated** coordinates by calculating Fourier series respectively by using the coefficients I got. For example,

```
Let's say I have a0_x, an_x, bn_x, a0_y, an_y, bn_y.
Then, Fx(t) = a0_x + an_x[1] * cos(1wt) + bn_x[1] * cos(1wt)
                   + an_x[2] * cos(2wt) + bn_x[2] * cos(2wt) + ...;

      Fy(t) = a0_y + an_y[1] * cos(1wt) + bn_y[1] * cos(1wt)
                   + an_y[2] * cos(2wt) + bn_y[2] * cos(2wt) + ...;

Therefore a set of points (Fx(t), Fy(t)) is an approximated path!
```

This is all! Only thing left is just drawing!

Meanwhile, I processed the data in the following way:

```js
const d = [svg path data];
const split = d.split(/[, ]/);
const points = get_points(split);
const normalized = normalize(points);
const populated = populate(normalized, 8);
const cx = populated.x; // Fx(t)
const cy = populated.y; // Fy(t)

/**
 * This function does the below job.
 * populate([0,3,6], 2) => output 0 12 3 45 6
 * populate([0,4,8], 3) => output 0 123 4 567 8
 */
function populate(data, n) {
  if (data.x.length <= 1) throw new Error('NotEnoughData');
  if (n < 1) throw new Error('InvalidNValue');

  const arr_x = new Array(data.x.length + (data.x.length - 1) * n);
  const arr_y = new Array(data.y.length + (data.y.length - 1) * n);

  for (let i = 0; i < data.x.length; i++) {
    arr_x[i * (n + 1)] = data.x[i];
    arr_y[i * (n + 1)] = data.y[i];
  }

  for (let i = 0; i <= arr_x.length - n - 1 - 1; i += (n + 1)) {
    const x_interpolation = (arr_x[i + n + 1] - arr_x[i]) / (n + 1);
    const y_interpolation = (arr_y[i + n + 1] - arr_y[i]) / (n + 1);

    for (let j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
      arr_x[i + j] = arr_x[i] + x_interpolation * j;
      arr_y[i + j] = arr_y[i] + y_interpolation * j;
    }
  }

  return { x: arr_x, y: arr_y };
}

// This function makes all values are in range of [-1, 1].
// I just did it... because I don't want to deal with big numbers (and not want numbers having different magnitude depending on data).
function normalize(obj) {
  const _x = [];
  const _y = [];

  const biggest_x = Math.max(...obj.x);
  const smallest_x = Math.min(...obj.x);
  const final_x = Math.max(Math.abs(biggest_x), Math.abs(smallest_x));

  const biggest_y = Math.max(...obj.y);
  const smallest_y = Math.min(...obj.y);
  const final_y = Math.max(Math.abs(biggest_y), Math.abs(smallest_y));

  for (let i = 0; i < obj.x.length; i++) {
    _x[i] = obj.x[i] / final_x;
    _y[i] = obj.y[i] / final_y;
  }

  return { x: _x, y: _y };
}

// returns Fx(t) and Fy(t) from svg path data
function get_points(arr) {
  const x = [];
  const y = [];
  let i = 0;

  while (i < arr.length) {
    const path_command = arr[i];

    if (path_command === "M") {
      x.push(Number(arr[i + 1]));
      y.push(Number(arr[i + 2]));
      i += 3;
    } else if (path_command === 'm') {
      if (i === 0) {
        x.push(Number(arr[i + 1]));
        y.push(Number(arr[i + 2]));
        i += 3;
      } else {
        x.push(x.at(-1) + Number(arr[i + 1]));
        y.push(y.at(-1) + Number(arr[i + 2]));
        i += 3;
      }
    } else if (path_command === 'L') {
      x.push(Number(arr[i + 1]));
      y.push(Number(arr[i + 2]));
      i += 3;
    } else if (path_command === 'l') {
      x.push(x.at(-1) + Number(arr[i + 1]));
      y.push(y.at(-1) + Number(arr[i + 2]));
      i += 3;
    } else if (path_command === 'H') {
      x.push(Number(arr[i + 1]));
      y.push(y.at(-1));
      i += 2;
    } else if (path_command === 'h') {
      x.push(x.at(-1) + Number(arr[i + 1]));
      y.push(y.at(-1));
      i += 2;
    } else if (path_command === 'V') {
      x.push(x.at(-1));
      y.push(Number(arr[i + 1]));
      i += 2;
    } else if (path_command === 'v') {
      x.push(x.at(-1));
      y.push(y.at(-1) + Number(arr[i + 1]));
      i += 2;
    } else if (path_command === 'Z' || path_command === 'z') {
      i++;
      console.log('reached to z/Z, getting points done');
    } else if (path_command === 'C' || path_command === 'c' || path_command === 'S' || path_command === 's' || path_command === 'Q' || path_command === 'q' || path_command === 'T' || path_command === 't' || path_command === 'A' || path_command === 'a') {
      throw new Error('unsupported path command, getting points aborted');
    } else {
      x.push(x.at(-1) + Number(arr[i]));
      y.push(y.at(-1) + Number(arr[i + 1]));
      i += 2;
    }
  }

  return { x, y };
}
```

Meanwhile, in order to calculate Fourier coefficients, I used numerical integration. This is the code.

```js
/**
 * This function calculates Riemann sum (area approximation using rectangles).
 * @param {Number} div division number (= number of rectangles to be used)
 * @param {Array | Function} subject subject of integration
 * @param {Number} start where to start integration
 * @param {Number} end where to end integration
 * @param {Number} nth this parameter will be passed to 'subject'
 * @param {Function} paramFn this parameter will be passed to 'subject'
 * @returns {Number} numerical-integrated value
 */
function numerical_integration(div, subject, start, end, nth = null, paramFn = null) {
  if (div < 1) throw new Error(`invalid div; it can't be 0 or 0.x`);

  let sum = 0;
  const STEP = 1 / div;
  const isSubjectArray = Array.isArray(subject);
  
  if (isSubjectArray) {
    for (let t = start; t < end; t++) {
      for (let u = 0; u < div; u++) {
        sum += subject[t + 1] * STEP;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (let t = start; t < end; t++) {
      for (let u = 0; u < div; u++) {
        const period = end - start;
        const isParamFnArray = Array.isArray(paramFn);

        if (isParamFnArray) sum += subject((t + 1), period, nth, paramFn) * STEP;
        else sum += subject(((t + STEP) + STEP * u), period, nth, paramFn) * STEP;
      }
    }
  }

  return sum;

// console.log(numerical_integration(10, (x) => x ** 3, 0, 2));
}
```

The approximation is near. For (x) => x, division 10, from 0 to 2, the approximation is 2.1 while actual answer is 2. For (x) => x ** 2, division 10, from 0 to 2, the approximation is 2.87, while actual answer is 2.67. For (x) => x ** 3, division 10, from 0 to 2, the approximation is 4.41, while actual answer is 4.

And I found a0, an, bn by the following: (※ You can find Fourier coefficients formulas in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70974735/a-problem-with-sound-producing-how-to-make-sound-with-fourier-coefficients))

```js
/**
 * This function will be passed to 'getAn' function.
 * @param {Number} t this function is a function of time
 * @param {Number} period period of a function to be integrated
 * @param {Number} nth integer multiple
 * @param {Array | Function} paramFn
 * @returns {Number} computed value
 */
function fc(t, period, nth, paramFn) {
  const isParamFnArray = Array.isArray(paramFn);
  const w = 2 * Math.PI / period;
  
  if (isParamFnArray) return paramFn[t] * Math.cos(nth * w * t);
  else return paramFn(t) * Math.cos(nth * w * t);
}

// This function will be passed to 'getBn' function.
function fs(t, period, nth, paramFn) {
  const isParamFnArray = Array.isArray(paramFn);
  const w = 2 * Math.PI / period;

  if (isParamFnArray) return paramFn[t] * Math.sin(nth * w * t);
  else return paramFn(t) * Math.sin(nth * w * t);
}

/**
 * This function returns a0 value.
 * @param {Number} period period of a function to be integrated
 * @param {Array | Function} intgFn function to be integrated
 * @param {Number} div number of rectangles to use
 * @returns {Number} a0 value
 */
// Why * 30? in order to scale up
// Why - 1? because arr[arr.length] is undefined.
function getA0(period, intgFn, div) {
  return 30 * numerical_integration(div, intgFn, 0, period - 1) / period;
}

/**
 * This function returns an values.
 * @param {Number} period period of a function to be integrated
 * @param {Number} div number of rectangles to use
 * @param {Number} howMany number of an values to be calculated
 * @param {Array | Function} paramFn function to be integrated
 * @returns {Array} an values
 */
function getAn(period, div, howMany, paramFn) {
  const an = [];

  for (let n = 1; n <= howMany; n++) {
    const value = 30 * numerical_integration(div, fc, 0, period - 1, n, paramFn) * 2 / period;
    
    an.push(value);
  }

  return an;
}

// This function returns bn values.
function getBn(period, div, howMany, paramFn) {
  const bn = [];

  for (let n = 1; n <= howMany; n++) {
    const value = 30 * numerical_integration(div, fs, 0, period - 1, n, paramFn) * 2 / period;

    bn.push(value);
  }

  return bn;
}

const xa0 = getA0(cx.length, cx, 10);
const xan = getAn(cx.length, 10, 100, cx);
const xbn = getBn(cx.length, 10, 100, cx);

const ya0 = getA0(cy.length, cy, 10);
const yan = getAn(cy.length, 10, 100, cy);
const ybn = getBn(cy.length, 10, 100, cy);
```

However, the result was not a thing I wanted... It was a weird shape... Maybe this is life...

[image: a weird shape]

The below is the canvas drawing code:

```js
const $cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
const cctx = $cvs.getContext('2d');

$cvs.setAttribute('width', 1000);
$cvs.setAttribute('height', 800);
$cvs.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid black;');
document.body.appendChild($cvs);

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw_tick);

// offset
const xoo = { x: 200, y: 600 }; // x oscillator offset
const yoo = { x: 600, y: 200 }; // y ~

// path
const path = [];

// drawing function
let deg = 0;

function draw_tick() {
  const rAF = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw_tick);

  // initialize
  cctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 800);
  
  // y oscillator
  const py = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  // a0
    // a0 circle
  cctx.beginPath();
  cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  cctx.arc(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y, Math.abs(ya0), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  cctx.stroke();

    // a0 line
  cctx.beginPath();
  cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  cctx.moveTo(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y);

  py.x += ya0 * Math.cos(0 * deg * Math.PI / 180);
  py.y += ya0 * Math.sin(0 * deg * Math.PI / 180);
  cctx.lineTo(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y);
  cctx.stroke();
  
  // an
  for (let i = 0; i < yan.length; i++) {
    const radius = yan[i];

    // an circles
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    cctx.arc(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y, Math.abs(radius), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    cctx.stroke();

    // an lines
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    cctx.moveTo(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y);

    py.x += radius * Math.cos((i+1) * deg * Math.PI / 180);
    py.y += radius * Math.sin((i+1) * deg * Math.PI / 180);
    cctx.lineTo(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y);
    cctx.stroke();
  }
  
  // bn
  for (let i = 0; i < ybn.length; i++) {
    const radius = ybn[i];

    // bn circles
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    cctx.arc(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y, Math.abs(radius), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    cctx.stroke();

    // bn lines
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    cctx.moveTo(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y);

    py.x += radius * Math.cos((i+1) * deg * Math.PI / 180);
    py.y += radius * Math.sin((i+1) * deg * Math.PI / 180);
    cctx.lineTo(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y);
    cctx.stroke();
  }

  // x oscillator
  const px = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  // a0
    // a0 circle
  cctx.beginPath();
  cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  cctx.arc(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y, Math.abs(xa0), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  cctx.stroke();

    // a0 line
  cctx.beginPath();
  cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  cctx.moveTo(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y);

  py.x += xa0 * Math.cos(0 * deg * Math.PI / 180);
  py.y += xa0 * Math.sin(0 * deg * Math.PI / 180);
  cctx.lineTo(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y);
  cctx.stroke();
  
  // an
  for (let i = 0; i < xan.length; i++) {
    const radius = xan[i];

    // an circles
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    cctx.arc(xoo.x + px.x, xoo.y + px.y, Math.abs(radius), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    cctx.stroke();

    // an lines
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    cctx.moveTo(xoo.x + px.x, xoo.y + px.y);

    px.x += radius * Math.cos((i+1) * deg * Math.PI / 180);
    px.y += radius * Math.sin((i+1) * deg * Math.PI / 180);
    cctx.lineTo(xoo.x + px.x, xoo.y + px.y);
    cctx.stroke();
  }

  // bn
  for (let i = 0; i < xbn.length; i++) {
    const radius = xbn[i];

    // bn circles
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    cctx.arc(xoo.x + px.x, xoo.y + px.y, Math.abs(radius), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    cctx.stroke();

    // bn lines
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    cctx.moveTo(xoo.x + px.x, xoo.y + px.y);

    px.x += radius * Math.cos((i+1) * deg * Math.PI / 180);
    px.y += radius * Math.sin((i+1) * deg * Math.PI / 180);
    cctx.lineTo(xoo.x + px.x, xoo.y + px.y);
    cctx.stroke();
  }

  // y oscillator line
  cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  cctx.beginPath();

  cctx.moveTo(yoo.x + py.x, yoo.y + py.y);
  cctx.lineTo(xoo.x + px.x, yoo.y + py.y);

  cctx.stroke();

  // x oscillator line
  cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  cctx.beginPath();

  cctx.moveTo(xoo.x + px.x, xoo.y + px.y);
  cctx.lineTo(xoo.x + px.x, yoo.y + py.y);

  cctx.stroke();

  // path
  path.push({ x: px.x, y: py.y });

  cctx.beginPath();
  cctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  
  cctx.moveTo(200 + path[0].x, 200 + path[0].y);

  for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    cctx.lineTo(200 + path[i].x, 200 + path[i].y);
  }

  cctx.stroke();

  // degree update
  if (deg === 359) {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(rAF);
  } else {
    deg++;
  }
}
```

So! I decided to be logical. First, I checked whether the converted path data is correct by drawing it at canvas. The below is the canvas code and the data.

```js
let count = 0;

function draw_tick2() {
  const rAF = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw_tick2);

  const s = 100; // scale up

  // initialize
  cctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 800);

  cctx.beginPath();
  
  // 200 has no meaning I just added it to move the path.
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (i === 0) cctx.moveTo(200 + s * cx[i], 200 + s * cy[i]);
    else cctx.lineTo(200 + s * cx[i], 200 + s * cy[i]);
  }

  cctx.stroke();

  if (count < cx.length - 1) {
    count++;
  } else {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(rAF);
  }
}
```

```js
const paimon = 'm 0,0 -2.38235,-2.87867 -1.58823,-1.29045 -1.9853,-0.893384 -3.17647,-0.39706 1.58824,-1.98529 1.09191,-2.08456 v -2.38235 l -0.79412,-2.87868 1.88603,2.18383 1.6875,1.88602 1.78677,0.99265 1.78676,0.39706 1.78676,-0.19853 -1.6875,1.58824 -0.69485,1.68749 -0.0993,2.084564 0.39706,2.18383 9.62867,3.87132 2.77941,1.9853 4.66544,-1.09192 3.07721,-1.88603 1.9853,-2.58088 -3.97059,0.49633 -3.375,-0.79412 -2.87868,-2.58088 -2.08456,-3.077214 2.38235,1.48897 2.08456,0.19853 3.57353,-0.89338 2.58089,-2.48162 -3.07721,0.39706 -3.87132,-1.88603 -2.97794,-2.08456 -2.48162,-2.87868 -3.87133,-4.06985 -4.06985,-2.68015 -5.95588,-2.58088 -5.85662,-0.79412 -5.45956,0.99265 0.59559,1.6875 -0.99265,1.09191 -0.79412,3.47427 -1.29044,-2.97794 -0.89338,-1.19118 0.79412,-1.48897 1.6875,-0.79412 0.39706,-3.772057 1.48897,1.290441 1.78676,0.09926 -2.08456,-1.985293 1.78677,-0.893382 4.36765,-0.19853 4.86397,0.992648 1.19117,1.091912 -2.38235,1.985301 3.17647,-0.49633 2.87868,-2.680149 -3.57353,-2.580881 -5.45956,-1.488972 h -4.46691 l -3.6728,-3.176471 -0.79412,1.389706 -0.79411,-1.488969 0.69485,-0.595588 -1.58824,-3.871325 -0.39706,3.672795 -0.69485,0.297794 0.89338,1.091911 v 1.091912 h -1.19113 l -0.59559,-0.992648 -1.98529,2.878677 -4.06986,1.588236 -4.26838,1.985293 3.27574,3.871329 2.87867,1.88603 2.58088,0.29779 -2.58088,-1.58823 -0.89338,-2.084566 4.86397,-0.992645 -1.19118,2.382351 h 1.58824 l 1.48897,-1.88603 0.29779,2.77942 -2.38235,2.38235 -3.57353,2.87868 -3.97059,4.86397 -2.08456,3.67279 -2.58088,2.58088 -2.68015,1.09192 -3.17647,0.0993 -1.3897,-0.69485 1.09191,3.17647 2.18382,3.573534 3.375,2.38235 -1.78676,5.85662 -1.38971,6.05514 0.39706,4.36765 1.38971,4.66544 3.87132,4.46691 -0.79412,-3.57352 -0.49632,-4.06986 v -2.48162 l 1.78676,5.85662 3.07721,3.17647 3.07721,1.29044 3.37499,0.79412 2.28309,-0.89338 0.69486,-1.48897 -1.19118,0.49632 -2.48162,-1.98529 -2.28309,-2.87868 2.28309,2.48162 h 0.99265 l 0.69485,-0.49632 0.2978,-1.19118 0.0993,-0.79412 -0.89339,0.59559 -1.58823,-0.99265 -1.29044,-1.3897 -1.19118,-2.38236 -0.89338,-4.86397 -0.0993,-4.56617 0.29779,-4.96324 0.39706,0.89338 1.19118,-0.44669 0.0496,-0.89338 1.09191,0.69485 1.48897,0.2978 1.53861,0.89338 0.99264,0.64522 h -0.79411 l 0.49632,2.43199 -0.44669,1.58823 -1.78676,0.39706 -1.24081,-1.24081 -0.24817,-1.43934 0.84375,-0.94301 1.19118,-0.49633 1.14154,0.94302 0.24816,1.14154 -0.0993,1.48897 -1.83639,0.64523 -1.58824,-1.53861 -0.44669,-1.48897 -0.24816,-2.18382 -1.43934,0.99264 0.0496,-0.99264 -0.44669,1.78676 0.69485,3.12684 1.09192,4.26838 1.78676,1.78677 6.89889,3.02757 -2.53124,0.99265 -3.17647,1.3897 -0.79412,0.39706 0.59559,0.39706 1.34007,-0.69485 0.0496,1.19117 1.98529,-0.39705 2.68015,-0.44669 -0.2978,-1.93567 0.79412,1.58824 2.82905,-0.44669 4.06985,-1.34008 1.04229,-0.59559 -0.2978,-1.78676 -0.34743,-1.73713 -4.9136,2.48162 -2.58088,0.94301 -3.17648,-4.81434 1.53861,0.49633 1.3897,0.0496 1.43935,-0.24816 -1.34008,0.24816 h -1.58824 l -1.41452,-0.54596 3.12684,4.78953 2.63052,-0.89339 4.86397,-2.4568 2.65533,-2.08456 0.39706,-5.90625 -0.84375,1.5386 -1.14155,0.54596 -1.5386,0.19853 -1.29044,-0.89338 -0.59559,-1.09191 -0.24816,-1.73714 0.24816,-1.3897 -2.08456,0.54595 -0.29779,-0.34742 0.34743,-0.49633 0.64522,-0.39706 1.5386,-0.39705 2.18382,-0.19853 1.24081,0.0993 1.14154,0.54596 0.4467,1.43934 -0.19853,1.63786 -0.59559,1.29044 -1.24081,0.89339 -1.43934,-0.39706 -0.99264,-1.09191 -0.0496,-1.19118 0.79412,-0.89338 0.89338,-0.44669 1.19118,-0.0496 0.64522,1.04228 0.34742,0.79412 -0.14889,1.14155 0.99265,-0.4467 0.29779,-1.34007 -0.19853,-4.06985 -1.93566,-0.44669 -2.53125,-1.6875 -2.23346,-1.88603 -2.23345,-4.069864 -0.44669,3.920964 0.64522,4.21875 1.5386,3.92096 0.74448,0.44669 h -1.73713 l -2.18383,-0.54596 -3.12684,-2.08456 -1.58823,-2.28309 -1.14154,-2.08456 -1.29044,-3.871324 -1.38971,2.481624 -1.48897,2.63051 -0.94302,1.9853 3.8217,-6.948534 1.29044,3.672794 2.33272,3.92096 2.9283,2.13419 0.49633,0.44669 2.28309,0.49632 h 1.63787 l -0.69485,-0.69485 -0.84375,-1.93566 -1.34008,-5.80698 0.44669,-3.970594 2.33273,4.069854 4.56617,3.47426 2.08456,0.59559 0.19853,2.82905 -0.0496,3.97058 -0.0993,6.00552 -0.54595,3.02757 -1.58824,2.77941 -1.5386,0.89339 -1.19118,0.24816 -1.48897,-0.69485 -0.69485,-0.1489 0.69485,1.24081 1.43934,1.6875 2.68015,1.19117 3.17647,0.2978 3.77206,-2.23346 1.3897,-2.77941 0.89339,-3.82169 0.0496,-3.375 0.14889,6.25368 -1.14154,5.11213 -2.08456,3.27573 -2.08456,1.6875 -1.88603,0.59559 -2.28308,-0.79412 1.78676,1.6875 4.9136,1.88603 2.43199,0.2978 2.68015,-0.39706 2.72977,-1.09191 3.62317,-3.27574 0.89338,-3.97059 0.49632,-3.57353 -0.0993,-2.87867 -0.39706,-3.17647 -0.49632,-3.07721 1.98529,3.47427 1.19117,2.18382 0.39706,1.29044 0.39706,-2.28309 -0.39706,-3.0772 -1.29044,-3.77206 -1.29044,-2.87868 -1.6875,-3.27573 -10.125,-4.16912 z';
```

[image: paimon chan]

This is ★Paimon chan★ from a computer game 'Genshin Impact'. Thus it is proved that there are no flaws at the data, since all the data is plotted correctly.

Next, I plotted the approximated (Fx(t), Fy(t)) points so that I can check whether there is a problem. And It turned out that there was a problem. But I don't understand what is the problem. At the same time this path is interesting; The beginning part of the path seems like the hairpin.

[image: a weird path]

This is the drawing code:

```js
function approxFn(t) {
  let x = xa0;
  let y = ya0;

  for (let i = 0; i < xan.length; i++) {
    x += xan[i] * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i * t / cx.length);
    x += xbn[i] * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * t / cx.length);
    y += yan[i] * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i * t / cx.length);
    y += ybn[i] * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * t / cx.length);
  }

  return { x, y };
}

function draw_tick3() {
  const rAF = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw_tick3);

  const s = 5;

  // initialize
  cctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 800);

  cctx.beginPath();

  for (let t = 0; t < count; t++) {
    if (count === 0) cctx.moveTo(200 + s * approxFn(t).x, 200 + s * approxFn(t).y);
    else cctx.lineTo(200 + s * approxFn(t).x, 200 + s * approxFn(t).y);
  }

  cctx.stroke();

  if (count < cx.length - 1) {
    count++;
  } else {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(rAF);
  }
}
```

The above is all the code in my js file. In where I made a mistake? It's a mystery! I know this question is exceptionally seriously long question. But please help me! I want to realize Paimon chan! ㅠwㅠ

※ (This section is irrelevant with the question) Meanwhile I made a success to draw the path in a **complex number plane**. If you're interested, please see my work... I would like to add circle things to this but I have no idea what is 'radius' in this case.

[image: complex Fourier coefficients]

[image: complex Fourier series]

[image: comparison of results of Fourier series]

```js
// You can see that I used real part for x and imaginary part for y.

for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      cctx.moveTo(coords[i].real * scaler + paimonPosition, coords[i].imag * scaler + paimonPosition);
    } else {
      cctx.lineTo(coords[i].real * scaler + paimonPosition, coords[i].imag * scaler + paimonPosition);
    }
  }
```

And this is the result. But what makes me confused is a case of cn = -5000 ~ 5000. As far as I understand, more cn, more accurate as original wave. But why it crashes when cn is so big?

Anyways, thank you very much for reading this long question!

Comment: I think you should reduce your question to a more specific issue... While your question is greatly formatted, it is far from "minimal" as defined in the [general guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: so if you are confident you parse the SVG correctly and compute/visualize simple series also correctly then problem will most likely have to do with `cn` ... however you never explain what `cn` is and its not present in code either... is it number of points or therms in series? You should create a MCVE ... so create a simple code and add path data that will reproduce your error ideally leave just rendering and series computing code  and instead of SVG parsing add hardcoded table of points extracted from SVG path ...

Comment: btw. from first look I taught you ignored transform matrices of SVG and rendered the correct mage using some lib or javascript native parser instead of yours.

Comment: I figured it out! I'll add details later. Thank you for giving me advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: fourier series animation at xy plane]
(the character shown: Paimon from Genshin Impact)

Hello myself!

**First**, errors in your code...

1. You did not consider a case where sequence of values come after drawing command. For example, your `get_points` function can't handle a case like `h 0 1 2`.
2. Current `get_points` function can't handle second `m` drawing command. You need to manually join strings if you have multiple paths.
3. You need to manually set m x y to m 0 0. Otherwise you can't see canvas drawing. (Maybe values are too too small to draw)

**Second**, in brief, you can't draw a shape with rotating vectors having fixed magnitude, if you approximate f(t) in a xy plane. It's because what you approximated is not a shape itself, but shape's coordinates.

**Third**, the reason you got weird shape when you tried to plot approximated data is at your `approxFn()` function.

```js
x += xan[i] * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i * t / cx.length);
x += xbn[i] * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * t / cx.length);
y += yan[i] * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i * t / cx.length);
y += ybn[i] * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i * t / cx.length);
```

not t, (t + 1) is correct. Your approximated data has no problem.

**Fourth**, so you need to take a complex plane approach if you want rotating vectors. In this case, the radius of circles are the magnitude of a sum vector of a real part vector and an imaginary part vector (Pythagorean theorem).

**Fifth**, In Cn formula, you missed 1 / T.

**Sixth**, The reason it crashed is... I don't know the exact reason but I think numerical integration and/or finding Cn is wrong. The new code I wrote don't crash at high Cn.

p.s. I wrote some writings about Fourier series. Please see if you are interested: https://logic-finder.github.io/memory/FourierSeriesExploration/opening/opening-en.html

Comment: Thanks for the demo in the website. I used the "Creation of Waveform" part to see the wave produced by the coefficients of a PeriodicWave that was creating a sound in an OscillatorNode.